# How do I get debug symbols linked to a python core dump of my shared object?

Tags: python, debugging, shared-libraries

I have python app that uses a shared library. This is my shared object, with sources and debug build.

The shared object gives a core dump on a running process and I try to debug it. I see all the threads and the backtrace but I can't view the source list. It says that `No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.`.

I thought that it loaded all the linked libraries but apparently not mine. How can I debug this? Why isn't the symbol table available for my shared object?

Thanks!

Comment: It could be tricky if the Python binary and/or the shared object in question haven't been built with debug symbols.

Comment: Python binary have been built without debug symbols and SO with. So the question is how can I solve this issue.